# Processing list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists and I want to process the information inside.

```py
lis = [[1,2,3,4],[1,5,6]]
```

I want to loop through this list of lists, such that I get `1 *(2*1/1) * (3*2/2) * (4*3/3)` and so on. Also, I know that multiplying and dividing by the same number returns the number you started with but I want to implicitly state it in the code. Performing this operation on the list should return

```py
list = [[24],[30]]
```

Comment: Your first term will be `1*0/0` which does not equal 1.

Comment: No I don't want to multiply and divide the first number by anything @c..

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does it fail?

Comment: @kichik I'm a beginner and the only way I can think of is hard coding the individual values but would not work on different sized lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to say with the arithmetic you wrote out, but this is probably what you're looking for.

```
from functools import reduce

lis = [[1,2,3,4],[1,5,6]]

list = [[reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, l)] for l in lis]
```

In a loop:

```
list = []

for l in lis:
    # do stuff here
    list.append(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, l))

print(list)
```

output:

`[[24], [30]]`

See [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

---

NOTE: For those trying to do this in a version before Python 3, I believe `reduce` is a built-in function.

Comment: If you wanted to go full-functional programming on this, can use `map(partial(reduce, mul), lis)` or the full version: `print map(functools.partial(functools.reduce, operator.mul), lis)`.  Note that the use of `map` or `operator.mul` can be used independently and injected into your answer.  Note that the map might need be wrapped in `list` for python3k, if you need a list back

Comment: is there a way to do this in a loop. I am trying to add an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication and division by the same number `*1/1` either `*2/2` in `1 *(2*1/1) * (3*2/2) * (4*3/3)` do not make much sense to me.

Using this function you may get the result that you are striving for, i.e. `[[24], [30]]`

```py
def list_mult(list_in):
    list_out = []
    for i in list_in:
        result = 1
        sub_list = []
        for j in i:
            result = result * j
        sub_list.append(result)
        list_out.append(sub_list)
    print(list_out)
```

Calling the function with `list_mult([[1,2,3,4],[5,6]])` will give `[[24], [30]]`.